# How to use predictions based on a Date column

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm fairly new on python and ML. I have a simple table that contains a date column and a float value. I want to predict the future sales for a given period, let's say `2022-01`, I managed to obtain a prediction based on my data but the number of prediction values is equal to the number of given trained values. Also, isn't the `meanSquaredError` value too high? So far, i got the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df=pd.read_csv(r"Sale.csv")
#Breaki date column into multiple columns
df["Data"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Data"])
df["Data"]=df["Data"].dt.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
df["Year"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Data"]).year
df["Month"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Data"]).month
df["Day"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Data"]).day
df["Weekday"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Data"]).weekday
df["Dayofyear"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Data"]).dayofyear

df=df.drop(["Data"],axis=1) #drop initial column

## Dummy Encoding
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Year'], drop_first=False, prefix='Year')
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Month'], drop_first=True, prefix='Month')
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Weekday'], drop_first=True, prefix='Weekday')

##split Train and test data
train=df.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=200) 
test=df.drop(train.index)

target_column_train=['Sales']
predictors_train= list(set(list(train.columns))-set(target_column_train))

X_train=train[predictors_train].values
y_train=train[target_column_train].values

##Loading ML model
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

model_rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=5000, oob_score=True, random_state=100)
model_rf.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel()) #.ravel will convert the array shape to (n, )

pred_train_rf= model_rf.predict(X_train)

print("RMSE:")
print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train,pred_train_rf))) 
# 7956042.545725489
print ("\n r2_score(Coefficient of determination:) is : ")
print(r2_score(y_train, pred_train_rf))
# 0.9284689685103222
```

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCJqH.png)

[DataVisualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c389s.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you run `model.predict` you are running it on your `x_train` rather than your `test` - that's why your prediction values are equal to that number. You want to `fit` your model on your train data, and `predict` on your test data.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. In this case, I have 16 results, that being the volume of the test sample

Comment: Did that clear up your issue, or is there something else? The high accuracy of your model means it has most likely overfit (great with this sample you give it, but bad at generalizing to future data)

Comment: That did not clear the answer, I want to predict a specific time in the future and it's not clear how I can realize that!

Comment: I suggest reading documentation and looking at other people's examples- If you have a specific question I'm happy to help. Start here: https://10mohi6.medium.com/super-easy-python-stock-price-forecasting-using-random-forest-machine-learning-1fccd9bb8672 . Then look into visualizing your model's predicted data. I suggest plotting your predictions on top of the actual data to get an idea of how your model is working.